# How to run Cucumber tests from inside a project to run on another project

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I want to run my command line tool in a project against another project to analyze Cucumber tests. Both projects have their own gemsets.

When I execute Cucumber pointing to the other project, then it tries to execute using my gemset/configuration, then it fails.

How can I "change scope/context" to make Cucumber run in the other project folder (and use its own Gemfile and configuration)?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
 Bundler.with_clean_env do
   system("cd other/project; bundle exec cucumber")
 end
```

Comment: Then I need more information, it should work. Maybe create a minimal example in a gist?

Comment: The "quick and dirty" solution was make a system call, then entering into the main project directory; run 'bundle install'; then 'cucumber features/'

Answer (score 0):

The "quick and dirty" solution was make a system call, then entering into the main project directory; run `bundle install`; then `cucumber features/`

`system("cd other/project && bundle install && bundle exec cucumber features/")`